# Daily alerts for cheapest flights anywhere at any given time?

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, flight-search-engines

You can search for flights from your location to "Everywhere" in Skyscanner.net. And the system will show you the cheapest flights first no matter the destination or date.

Every day prices change, so it would be very useful to receive daily, weekly or monthly updates via email for the current cheapest flights "Everywhere".

Is there a service that can provide this?

Comment: Adioso, but I think this question is duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

Found two ways to do this:

1) [Adioso.com](http://adioso.com) is able to schedule alerts for cheap flights anywhere from my location.

2) A [website monitoring tool](http://visualping.io) will alert whenever a change is made in the custom search results made by Skyscanner.net. That means cheap flights notifications anywhere at any date.

Skyscanner results are cheaper and more flexible than Adioso for the moment.